# Sending animated gifs and videos with Microsoft Botbuilder to Skype endpoints

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype

I am building a bot service to communicate to various endpoints. I have Skype basic communication running through Microsoft Botbuilder in Nodejs. I can send text to the Skype client fine, however when I want to send rich messages with images (animated gifs) or videos, things start going haywire.

1) Sending a animated gif:

```
function createAnimationCard(session) {
    return new builder.AnimationCard(session)
        .title('Microsoft Bot Framework')
        .subtitle('Animation Card')
        .image(builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/images/faq-overview/botframework_overview_july.png'))
        .media([
        { url: 'http://i.giphy.com/Ki55RUbOV5njy.gif' }
    ]);
}
```

I call this code from another function:

```
exports.sendGif = function sendGif(chatBotUserSession, picUrl, contentType) {
    var card = createAnimationCard(chatBotUserSession);
    var reply = new builder.Message(chatBotUserSession).addAttachment(card);
    _bot.send(reply);
};
```

When I do this I get to see an image with a play button (in the desktop Skype, mobile client does not show image at all), however pressing the button shows an error "opening not possible". I have tried different gif sources in the url field, but none seem to work. Also tried https for source.

2) I then moved to trying to display a video:

```
function createVideoCard(session) {
    return new builder.VideoCard(session)
        .title('Big Buck Bunny')
        .subtitle('by the Blender Institute')
        .text('Big Buck Bunny (code-named Peach) is a short computer-animated comedy film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation. Like the foundation\'s previous film Elephants Dream, the film was made using Blender, a free software application for animation made by the same foundation. It was released as an open-source film under Creative Commons License Attribution 3.0.')
        .image(builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg'))
        .media([
            { url: 'http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4' }
         ])
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://peach.blender.org/',    'Learn More')
    ]);
}
```

When I call this using:

```
exports.sendMovie = function sendMovie(chatBotUserSession, picUrl, contentType) {
    var card = createVideoCard(chatBotUserSession);
    var reply = new builder.Message(chatBotUserSession).addAttachment(card);
    _bot.send(reply);
};
```

It all works... at least on my desktop Skype. My mobile skype (iOS) now crashes each time when I open the chat with my bot...

So two questions:
1) Does anyone know why I can't seem to send animated gifs that actually play?
2) Anyone have experience with bots on mobile Skype sending rich content and consequently crashing the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you hosting this chatbot via Azure Bot Service?

Comment: Nope, running this code on my own servers.

Comment: There's a known issue with AnimationCards that has been fixed in the latest release of Skype iOS v6.35.0.44

Comment: That did indeed solve the crash issue. Thanks. Now still trying to find why gifs don't play. Where did you find the known issues list?